Best way to deny .php in URLs while keeping access to those files through other URLs
Here are two examples of what I would like to do:
Example 1: I have a services.php file. I would like it to be accessible on www.example.com/services. Furthermore, I would like www.example.com/services.php to redirect to www.example.com/services.
Example 2: I have index.php file. I would like it to be accessible on www.example.com. Furthermore, I would like www.example.com/index.php and www.example.com/home to redirect to www.example.com.
I have been looking online for a solution but could not find anything. I came up with the following Apache code for my .htaccess file:
RewriteRule ^services$ services.php [END]
RewriteRule ^services.php$ /services [R=301]

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [END]
RewriteRule ^home$ / [R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301]

The code above does the job, but I am unsure if that is the optimal solution. In the best-case scenario, I believe that there should be no redirects when accessing www.example.com/services and www.example.com, and only a single redirect when accessing www.example.com/services.php, www.example.com/index.php and www.example.com/home. I am worried that my code might be doing 1 additional redirect for each but I do not know how to check that. Can I get some assistance, please?
Edit: I would also like to make services in www.example.com/services case insensitive so that something like www.example.com/sERvICeS would correctly show the content of services.php. That would normally be done with the NC but I cannot do that. It seems like using the END flag makes it impossible to use the NC one.
RewriteRule ^services$ services.php [NC, END]
RewriteRule ^services.php$ /services [R=301]

The code above leads to an Internal Server Error. The above was fixed by removing the space between NC and END [NC,END].
Edit 2: Is there any way to support NC for Russian characters as well? I have a few paths that are in Russian on my website. I have tried implementing a solution as proposed in the comments. Unfortunately, it does not work. When Cyrillic characters are put in brackets they stop working.
RewriteRule ^новост[иИ]$ news.php

For example, the RegEx above would not match any path. Neither новости nor новостИ nor any other.
RewriteRule ^новост[иS]$ news.php

Meanwhile, the RegEx above would match новостS but not match новости. Therefore, it seems like English characters are working just right. I have been looking for a solution online but I could not find anything relevant.

Use your browser dev tools, network panel - you'll be able to easily see in there, which request(s) get a redirect response.

but I do not know how to check that...watch what happens in your browser's Network tool

I just learned about this tool and provided that I am using it correctly, my solution seems to be behaving (what I believe is) optimally. Still, I might be overlooking something. If someone spots a problem in my solution or if there is a more template way of doing this, please let me know.

If you want a code review of a working solution, go to the Code Review Stackexchange site. This Stackoverflow site is for problems with code that isn't working as designed. Thanks!

Your solution is very specific, it only works for those two cases. You could create a more general rule. Something like: "Every url without an extension, that is not a existing file or directory on the server, should get a .php extension.". You then would need to create a /home.php script for the /home url to also work.

Well, I did not know if my code worked as designed which is why I made the thread. It turns out it does. I have made an edit to describe the problem I have encountered.

[NC, END] invalidates the whole rule. Multiple flags must be separated by comma only, without any additional whitespace.

That worked, thanks. Do you know if there is any way to support NC for Russian characters as well? I have a few paths that are in Russian on my website.

I don't think the NC flag will work for Russian/Cyrillic - due to how "English-centric" the web developed, such basic functionality is often limited to a-z only. But if you only need this for a handful URLs, I suppose you could solve it by using character classes: ^[sS][eE][rR][vV][iI][cC][eE][sS]$ - in each "position", one of the two characters from the class is required - so this works for services however you spell it, Services, serVICES, sERvIcEs, etc. And you should be able to do the same with corresponding lowercase/uppercase classes containing Cyrillic characters instead.

I could do that. However, some of the paths contain up to about 50 Cyrillic characters in total. Do you think that doing the above 50 times could cause any performance issues? I do not know much about RegEx but based on what I have heard it is very quick so I would imagine it would not cause any problems.

Regex can easily become problematic in that regard, when the lengths of parts of what you are trying to match are dynamic, so that it needs to start backtracking to figure out if there is a match or not - but that is not the case here. Everything is "fixed length", and in each position, it only needs to check if the character is one of two given alternatives - and as soon as it encounters the first character that isn't a match any more, the whole process can be ended at this point. As far as regex go, this is really low complexity - should be absolutely fine here, for the intended purpose.

I have implemented the solution above and it is unfortunately not working. When Cyrillic characters are put in brackets they stop working.  For example, ^новост[иИ]$ would not match any path. Neither новости nor новостИ nor any other. Meanwhile, ^новост[иS]$ would match новостS but not match новости. Therefore, it seems like English characters are working just right. I have been looking for a solution online but I could not find anything relevant. I have edited my post to reflect those findings.
